# Can a form be referenced as variable in VB or C# .NET as you would do with controls?

Tags: .net, vb.net, forms, variables, declaration

I have several different forms that share common procedures

The only difference with these procedures would be which form the controls would be on for a particular request.

So my first thought was to do something like this:

```
Dim currentForm As Form = Nothing
Select Case requestedForm
Case "Form1"

    currentForm = Form1

Case "Form2"

    currentForm = Form2

End Select

currentForm.textbox1.text = "stuff"
```

Is it possible to do this without creating a `NEW` instance?

The only other way I could think to do it was declare each control within the select.

```
Select Case requestedForm

   Case "Form1"

     Dim currentTextBox1 As TextBox = Form1.textbox1
     Dim currentTextBox2 As TextBox = Form1.textbox2
     Dim currentTextBox3 As TextBox = Form1.textbox3

   Case "Form2"

     Dim currentTextBox1 As TextBox = Form2.textbox1
     Dim currentTextBox2 As TextBox = Form2.textbox2
     Dim currentTextBox3 As TextBox = Form2.textbox3

End Select

currentTextBox1.text = "stuff"
currentTextBox2.text = "things"
currentTextBox3.text = "more"
```

Comment: "Is it possible to do this without creating a NEW instance?" no.  And since `Form2` and `Form2` are different types there's not a way to polymorphically access their `textbox1` properties.

Comment: Are you wanting to perhaps have a method in Form2 mess with the controls on Form1?  Dont do that

Comment: You _could_ have them inherit from an interface that sets those properties, but without knowing more it's hard to say if that's a valid approach.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses, I'm just going to declare the controls. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something simple and end up wasting the time.   I'm betting that customer controls would have been much better.     Live and learn, thanks again

Comment: "customer controls???"  That last snippet will not compile, BTW.  `Select Case` creates a local scope so those references dont exist outside the Case statement

Comment: I just meant one form that adapts instead of multiple forms for different needs.